# EditText text selector background block?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I'm having an issue with the text selector handle in an `EditText` field.

[image]

The text handle appears to have a background color that blocks out the text below.

How do I get it so it's a transparent background?

Here is the relevant xml resource snippet

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout_register_username"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textInputLayout_login_password"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="@string/username_hint"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/login_username"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable long click

android:longClickable = "false"

Comment: That didn't do anything.

Comment: Then do one thing create own draw able or create own cursor image and set as textcursoredrawable

Comment: In Layout

<EditText  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/color_cursor"
    />
Then create drawalble xml: color_cursor

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <size android:width="3dp" />
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"  />
</shape>

Answer (score 0):

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

use this it perfectly work for and i hope for u too.